# iterate through the objects of a class

Tags: java, class, object, iteration

I have created this class.

```
public class UserData {

    private int user_Id;
    private List<String> disease_List=new LinkedList<String>();
    /*Constructor*/
    public UserData(int u_id, List<String> d_list)
    {
        this.user_Id=u_id;
        this.disease_List=d_list;
    }
}
```

I created around 500 objects by reading data from file.
Now I want to **search for values**. For example If user enters a disease= allergy.
I want to **iterate through all objects** and display users that have allergy in disease_list.
I have searched on internet for this but have not found anything useful.

Comment: It's not clear how you missed the java.util.Iterator on your internet researches, but this would be a candidate...

Comment: There is no way to iterate through all objects. Instead, you should add the objects to a list.

Comment: No need even for that - just `if (user.disease_List.contains(disease))` should be fine to check a single user. Do you *have* a collection of users already? Your question is fairly vague on that point.

Comment: I found that I can do it by creating maps. But what is the purpose of creating class when i'm again adding it in maps??

Comment: @JonSkeet This is exact;y what i want to ask. that i have to create some other maps or there is any direct method. and i want to find all users that contain disease

Comment: Judging from the description there should be another outer collection of `UserData` since you've mentioned `display users that have...`? Could you show this outer collection code?

Comment: @Sheldon cooper: The purpose is you can have many instance variables(attributes). Say tomorrow if you are going to add user contacts you can add them in userData class and access them.

Comment: @sheldoncooper: Well "all users that contain disease" suggests you need an "all users overall" collection to start with, and you're *still* not clear on whether that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the userData objects in a collection and iterate them and access it's attributes say disease_list.

For example, if you've added the userData objects in a arrayList, you can iterate in the following way

```
for(UserData user:UserDataList){
        if(user.disease_list.contains("allergy") {
         //display the user details
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood the question.. But basically what you want to do is search for a certain keyword in the disease_List inside every UserData object, right?

So say you have added a `String allergy = "allergy";` inside the disease_list.

What you want to do in order to find this you need to iterate through the disease_list instance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < disease_list.size(); i++) {
    if(disease_list.get(i).equals("allergy")){
        //Now you know this UserData object contains "allergy". Now you
        //can choose to break the iteration and do something with
        //the object.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambdas expression (with java 8 or higher) to sort lists.

```
public class UserData {

private int user_Id;
private ArrayList<String> diseases;
/*Constructor*/
public UserData(int u_id, ArrayList<String> d_list)
{
    this.user_Id=u_id;
    this.diseases=d_list;
}

public ArrayList filter(String disease) {
    return Arrays.stream(diseases).filter(x -> x.equal(disease)).toArray();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't just automatically make a list of every object you create, you need to make the list yourself.

```
public class UserData {

    /* This must exist somewhere */
    private static List<UserData> everyone = new LinkedList<UserData>();
    private int user_Id;
    private List<String> disease_List=new LinkedList<String>();
    /*Constructor*/
    public UserData(int u_id, List<String> d_list)
    {
        this.user_Id=u_id;
        this.disease_List=d_list;
        everyone.append(this);
    }

    /* Iterator for all the objects */
    public static Iterator<UserData> iterator() {
        return everyone.iterator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to iterate here is one way

```
for(String disease:disease_list){
if(disease.equalsIgnoreCase("allergy")
   log.info("You find out the Result");
}
```

else you can use `contains()` method

```
if(disease_list.contains("allergy")){
log.info("found the disease");
}
```